# Undefined function from cgo

Tags: go

Trying to do my first steps with `cgo` at Win10, so I read [this](https://karthikkaranth.me/blog/calling-c-code-from-go/) and [this](https://www.thegoldfish.org/2019/04/using-c-libraries-from-go/) and made the below:

```sh
C:/cgo> go mod init hasan/lib
C:/cgo> code .
```

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export HelloWorld
func HelloWorld() {
    fmt.Printf("hello world")
}

func main() {}
```

Compiled it as:

```sh
C:/cgo> go build -buildmode=c-shared
C:/cgo> dir
 Directory of C:\cgo

06/06/2020  02:23 PM    <DIR>          .
06/06/2020  02:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/06/2020  01:41 PM                26 go.mod
06/06/2020  02:23 PM         3,503,249 lib
06/06/2020  02:23 PM             1,580 lib.h
06/06/2020  01:42 PM               170 main.go
               4 File(s)      3,505,025 bytes
```

The created another module into another directory `cgotest` created go file named `hello.go` and copied both `lib` and `lib.h` into it:

```sh
C:/cgotest> dir
 Directory of C:\cgotest

06/06/2020  02:18 PM    <DIR>          .
06/06/2020  02:18 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/06/2020  02:17 PM                24 go.mod
06/06/2020  02:18 PM               134 hello.go
06/06/2020  02:18 PM         3,503,249 lib
06/06/2020  02:18 PM             1,580 lib.h
               4 File(s)      3,504,987 bytes
```

The `hello.go` is:

```golang
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "lib.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    HelloWorld()
}
```

And tried to use `go run` but got error as below:

```sh
D:\cgotest>go run .
# lintest
.\hello.go:9:2: undefined: HelloWorld
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment, i tried:

```golang
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "lib.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.HelloWorld()
}
```

But got:

```sh
D:\cgotest>go run .
# lintest
C:\Users\HASAN~1.YOU\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build829713742\b001\_x002.o: In function `_cgo_cd3f93e214f7_Cfunc_HelloWorld':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:49: undefined reference to `HelloWorld'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# lintest
cgo-gcc-prolog: In function '_cgo_cd3f93e214f7_Cfunc_HelloWorld':
cgo-gcc-prolog:47:49: warning: unused variable '_cgo_a' [-Wunused-variable]
```

**UPDATE 2**
Once I run the same at Mac OS, I got the below error:

```sh
Hasans-MacBook-Air:cgo hasan$ go run .
# hasan/cgo
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_HelloWorld", referenced from:
      __cgo_cad3974428dd_Cfunc_HelloWorld in _x002.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_cad3974428dd_Cfunc_HelloWorld)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
# hasan/cgo
cgo-gcc-prolog:47:33: warning: unused variable '_cgo_a' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: You call a C function using the  `C.` package prefix, just like in the examples you linked.

Comment: @JimB kindly see my updated question based on your feedback.

Comment: Not sure offhand. Loading Go through cgo in Go isn't really supported, so I'm not sure what the failure modes look like.